# How do you load a season in MLB 2K6?

Tags: xbox-360

We just got an Xbox 360 for the kids and I bought an old cheap game: *MLB 2K6*.  My son was able to figure out how to start and save a season under VIP1, and we can go under Manage Seasons.  But he and I can not figure out how to load the seasons up so it continues playing. Do I need to have an Xbox Live account setup to do that?

What are the steps to load the seasons?  When he hits play it gives him the choices to pick two new teams to start a game, but those are not for the season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2K6 games are set up differently from EA's sports games (not that it matters now, as EA's pushed 2K out of most sports), and the menu system is not easy to figure out. To load a season that you've created,

1. From the Main Menu, select **My 2K6**. A menu will appear on the right side of the screen.
2. Select **Save/Load**. The menu on the right side will change.
3. Select **Load**. You'll get a prompt from the 360 to select a device - this is the standard dialog box across all games that the 360 uses. Select the device on which the games are stored; it's most likely your hard drive. The 360 menu will close and the Load menu will appear.
4. Every type of file that has been saved will appear on this screen. Look in the Type column for Season; this is the season file (probably called Season1) that your son saved. Select the saved season.
5. A dialog box will appear that says "Caution: Loading now will lose any of your previously unsaved changes. Continue?" Select **Yes**.

You should get a message that the season is loading and then a dialog box telling you that it was successfully loaded.